# Select AWS RDS Aurora into S3 encrypted bucket with KMS

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, amazon-kms

I'm trying to use AWS RDS Aurora functionality `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE S3 :some_bucket/object_key` where `some_bucket` has default Server-side encryption with KMS.

I'm receiving this error, which makes sense:

`InternalError: (InternalError) (1871, u'S3 API returned error: Unknown:Unable to parse ExceptionName: KMS.NotFoundException Message: Invalid keyId')`

How can I make this work, make Aurora have the KMS key so that it can upload a file into S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html#AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.Statement

> Compressed or encrypted files are not supported.

But you could create an exception policy for the bucket with  "NotResource" policy for particular suffix and select into that, from there you could trigger an lambda to move the file to actual path with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Aurora MySQL currently supports this. Follow the above official documentation for adding an IAM role to your RDS cluster, and make sure the role has policies granting both S3 read/write and KMS encryption/decryption, e.g.

```
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<account>:key/<key id>"
        }
```